# Cancelling a StreamSubscription in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following stream subscription

```
Stream<Uint8List> stream = await USBSerialSingleton.instance.inputStream;
usbStream = stream.listen(onDataReceivedFromUSBSerial);
```

The `inputStream` is a broadcast stream exposed like this.

```
Future<Stream<Uint8List>> get inputStream async {
final UsbPort port = await this.port;
return port.inputStream.asBroadcastStream();
}
```

I would like to stop listening to the stream, so I am calling

```
usbStream.cancel();
```

But I keep receiving messages on my `onDataReceivedFromUSBSerial` method. I keep getting messages on the `onDataReceivedFromUSBSerial` even if I close the dialogue that all this is implemented on.

Question: How do I stop listening to my `usbStream`?

Comment: What you are doing looks correct. Are you sure it's the correct `usbStream` subscription you are cancelling?

Comment: @pskink any idea why mine is not cancelling?

Comment: @lrn yup, pretty sure.

Comment: Is the stream not cancelling because there is still data coming out of the USB connection? Or maybe because there is another widget listening to the broadcast stream?

Comment: [StreamSubscription - cancel method](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-async/StreamSubscription/cancel.html) docs say that: After this call, the subscription no longer receives events. The stream may need to shut down the source of events and clean up after the subscription is canceled. 

There might still be data coming from the USB connection as you mentioned.

Comment: Try `await usbStream.cancel();`

Comment: @dev-aentgs Yeh, there is data coming from the connection. I don't need to listen to the data once I have closed the dialogue.

Comment: @DrkStr does `await` for then `cancel` works?

Comment: Maybe you are subscribed multiple times and only cancel once.

Comment: Be sure that your subscribing method is called just once... also, close the entire app and try again.. sometimes you has done something wrong and one of your old subscriptions do not be closed properly...

Comment: @mFeinstein. Apologies for the delayed reply. Just had a chance to try out the await. Looks like that did the trick. If you could post that as an answer, ill accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to await for the subscription cancelation so do:

```
await usbStream.cancel();
```